# View.setTag - need multiple keys: resourceIDs

Tags: android, view

I'm creating a custom View to be included in a class library. I need to add multiple tags to subviews that I am creating dynamically (in code, not xml), so this requires that I add use: **View.setTag(int key, Object tag)**.

The key needs to be an id defined in the project R file, but since all of my views are dynamically created and the code is going into a library for use in other projects, I don't have a hardcoded resource id on hand to use. Is there any way to discover a couple of defined resource ids programatically, or to define some programatically?  Or am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can add *any* object as a tag.  If the data you're adding to the view is dynamic, then the easiest thing to do would be to add a Hashtable to the View as the tag.  Then add all the key/value pairs you want to that Hashtable.  On the other end, (the code processing the tag), you can iterate over the values by casting the View's tag back into a Hashtable, and iterating over [Hashtable.keys()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Hashtable.html#keys%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the replies kabuko and Alex. I was hoping not to have to use another data structure but I guess it solves my problem and it adds only negligible complexity. Giving answer to Alex, since he answered first and both answers are the same...

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29), it says:

> Tags can also be used to store data within a view without resorting to another data structure.

Implying that something you could do is to use another data structure. You might want to look 
at using the [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) pattern and storing an instance of that in the tag.